# Disable Visual Studio green arrow button moving instruction pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Recently Visual Studio is displaying a green arrow while debugging, when hovering with the mouse.

If you click on it it moves the instruction pointer to that line, I think.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: Do you mean the `Run execution to here` button?

Comment: Yes I think that's that.

Comment: I have learned in the most part to avoid clicking on this but at first it was very very annoying and disruptive to my debugging process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Run execution to here` can be disabled the following way:

Tools `->` Options `->` Debugging `->` General

And unticking `Show Run to click button while debugging`.

This is in VS Community 2019, slight variations can occur in other versions.

Comment: When using Unity this Green Play from here Arrow crashes the client with a hard error.
Thanks for helping remove this annoyance